# BaseAdapter Scroll view not working inside Scroll

Tags: android, listview

BaseAdapter Scroll view not working inside Scrollview android

using : base adapter
please share ideas regarding how to working scrollview list inside scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Base adapter is scrollable automatically. You dont need to insert it inside scrollview. Put base adapter outside scrollview, and it will work.

Comment: i know its working fine outside of scrollview bt i have requirement to use inside scrollview so any soln regarding

Answer (score 0):

Step1- Create an Activity name-MainActivity.java and create a listview.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       private String listview_array[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE",
                     "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };
       ListView myList;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
              myList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
              Helper.getListViewSize(myList);

       }
}
```

Step2- Create main.xml-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Step3- Finally and important thing create another class Helper.java and put below given code-

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Helper {
    public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            //do nothing return null
            return;
        }
        //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
      //setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        // print height of adapter on log
        Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide me solution with baseadpater